# Best way to implement Spring HATEOAS when we've BFF with Angular 8?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-hateoas

I went through few tutorial links: https://dzone.com/articles/applying-hateoas-to-a-rest-api-with-spring-boot and https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/rest-with-spring-hateoas-example/, but looks like this is not proper implementation of the `Spring HATEOAS`.

When I went through Spring Doc, I find that we should be using ResourceAssemblerSupport which will wrap our Entity with the DTO/Resource class.

Can anyone please guide me on how to properly implement Spring HATEOAS where we have BFF (Backend For Frontend)?